Trane comfort 2 thermostat keeps going blank
I have a Trane Comfort 2 thermostat and  Trane TAM8A0C48V41CAA AC / heat pump.  We were gone on vacation for a week. I wanted to turn the fan from auto to on because the air in the house seemed a little stale when I noticed the display was totally blank. I took the thermostat off the wall and looked for batteries to change, but there didn't seem to be any. I plugged it in and it worked okay for a while, but then the display turned off again.  I looked at the unit in the basement and it's saying
ALEET 1 AFC
SYS COMM ERR

It sounds to me like it's lost the connection to the thermostat.  I'm wondering what to check.  The thermostat will work for a while then go blank, turning off the AC.
There were only 3 wires Red, White, and Blue. The corresponding terminals are labeled D, R, B.  I have a multimeter, I'm wondering what voltages I should see if the wiring is OK.  I'm seeing 12.5 VDC from white to red and white to blue.  I'm seeing 0 VDC from red to blue.
I've changed thermostats a couple times

Have you looked in the heat pump manual for the meaning of the displayed messages and for any troubleshooting instructions?

Thermostats use nominal 24VAC. You might consider repeating your voltage measurements on the VAC scale. Don't be alarmed by higher voltage up to 30ish.

I double checked it's 12.5 V.  On the back of the thermostat D is Data, R is R, and B is labeled C.

This thermostat expects to see 18-32VAC on the thermostat wire. If it's getting only 12.5V that's a likely reason that it's going blank. Measure voltage on the thermostat wires at the heat pump end. If it's circa 24VAC, you have a broken or loose thermostat wire somewhere. If it's not circa 24VAC either the 24V transformer is bad or you have a partial short circuit somewhere, dropping the voltage.

It appears your thermostat is a "communicating" type, which means that it uses a two-way digital communication between the thermostat and the air handler. Unfortunately this means 99% of the information you'll read online about thermostats, wire color codes, expected voltages, and so on does not apply.
The message "SYS COMM ERR" appears to indicate a communication problem, as you already guessed. You can do basic things to check the integrity of the cable itself:

wiggle the wires in the terminals/connectors to check whether any is loose
inspect the portion of the cable that you can see to check for any damage such as small cuts in the insulation, rodent damage, etc
could disconnect both ends of the cable from the equipment, then short pairs of colors together and measure at the other end with an ohm meter to ensure that you see shorts and opens as expected

One other thing: you could get a bit of wire/cable and try wiring the thermostat directly to the air handler right there in the same room. This test would eliminate the variable of the cable that's installed in the house. If you still have trouble with this arrangement then you can be confident there's a fault in the thermostat or in the air handler -- but it won't be clear which has the problem.
Beyond that... good luck. You might be able to find some diagnostic or troubleshooting info specific to your model/family of equipment.
